# Differential operator acting on a constant

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

When a differential operator acts on a constant does this equal 0 or just the constant? For example

$ F_x a $

Where Fx is the first order difference operator and a is constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a Derivative means the limit of the ratio of the change in a function to the corresponding change in its independent variable as the latter change approaches zero.

A constant remains constant irrespective of any change to any variable in the function therefore, its derivative is $0$.